# Some counterexamples in basic ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

Give an example if possible, and if not possible explain why not.

a) A subring of a PID that is not PID.

b) A PID that is a subring of a non-PID.

c) A subring of a PID that is not UFD.

**My approach:**

**a)** Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is field then $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is PID. But it's subring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$  is not PID because the ideal $(2,x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not principal.

**b)** Consider the subring $\mathbb{Z}$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. We know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is euclidean domain  and hence is PID.

**c)** Consider the subring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ of the ring $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$. I know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not UFD, but $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+5)$ and since $x^2+5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ then it's  field $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is also field $\Rightarrow$ is PID.

Are my examples correct?

Would be very grateful!

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Each question has been answered at this site already. You could also compare. For example, b) is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543215/a-pid-that-is-a-sub-ring-of-a-non-pid?rq=1). For a), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001631/subring-of-pid-is-also-a-pid). Actually, you have the same example.

Comment: Try subrings of a polynomial ring over a field, $k[x]$